# OS X Finder: Arrow keys navigation in icons view

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion, finder, keyboard-navigation

Is there a way to enable a “wrap around” arrow keys navigation in Mac Finder? Right now, I found that if I have highlighted the first or the last item in a row, I cannot use the left/right arrow key to jump to the row above/below. For example:

[image: finder screenshot]

I won’t be taken to the “TTMIK Level 1 Lesson 22 PDF.pdf” file from the current position, if I press the left arrow key. This is pretty annoying, especially when I use quick look to browse through a bunch of files displayed in icons mode. To get this to work, I have to switch to columns or list view, which isn’t always preferred.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not possible (at least not without dirty hacks?). What you can do however is to tab through the items.

- To navigate to the next item, press ⇥
- To navigate to the previous item, press ⇧⇥

This will also cycle through the items. Therefore, when you've reached the end, you'll start at the beginning.

This also works if Quick Look is activated.

Comment: This is better than nothing, although not as handy as arrow keys. I hope this will get fixed in the future. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The year is 2020 and they have not fixed a simple move to next selection! Perhaps will have to visit 10 years later.

Comment: oh this is great!! tab is better than arrows i feel anyway.. easier to reach on the keyboard!